# Doctest: how to not count a setup line as a test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, doctest

```
import doctest
__test__['test'] = \
"""
>>> y = 1
>>> y == 1
True
"""
```

Expected: 0 failed, 1 attempted

Actual: 0 failed, 2 attempted

How do I tell doctest that the first line is just setup, not a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you care about this, don't use `doctest`** (use `unittest` or the like which has a concept of setup separate from tests).

That said, **it does not matter, at all, if it counts as a test, because if you fail *any* tests, your code is broken.** Who cares if your code says 2/2 tests succeeded vs. 1/1, the real result of your tests is boolean: Did 100% of them pass? If not, your tests *failed*. Everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: Note: If you *really* want to do this, [the `doctest` advanced API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#advanced-api) allows you to override any of the associated classes, and you could probably make this work by overriding the runner or the checker class. The work involved is likely greater than just writing stuff as `unittest` tests in the first place though, it adds more points of failure, and as noted, additional "tests" that always succeed are 100% irrelevant, so don't bother.

Comment: From a development point of view, the aim is to reach zero failure. But there are other uses for (doc)tests. One use case that comes to mind is automatically grading homework. If half of your "tests" consist in setting up variables for further use, then a student who failed to implement all the assigned functions should get a score of 0, and not half of the total.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: Tests like that can just as easily be written as `unittest` tests. You can put doctests in the skeletons to have the students self-check, but it's not like you could just run the doctests and mark the points; if they're part of the submitted work, the student could have screwed them up themselves, so now you're stuck rechecking to make sure they weren't changed (I say this having taught Python, to adults, with exercises full of doctests for self-checks; there's *always* some student who, inadvertently or otherwise, deletes/disables the doctests).

Comment: In short: doctests are the easy, but low configurability/power, solution. They're not the robust testing framework you'd need for just about anything where anything other than the boolean "did all the tests pass?" check is important. If you want configurability (say, to skip tests based on the host features or command line flags, separate setup from tests, perform more complicated tests based on stuff other than simple REPL-like echoing, etc.), you need a better system.

Comment: Duly noted. I'll have a look at `unittest` for this specific application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a straightforward option to achieve that. My strategy has been to mark setup lines as such in my test files:

```
>>> y = 1  # SETUP
>>> y == 1
True
```

and then to run tests with `doctest.testfile`:

```
failures, tests = doctest.testfile("my_tests.txt")
```

after which I subtract from `tests` the number of setup lines:

```
nb_setup = 0
with open(test_file) as data:
    for line in data:
        nb_setup += line.strip().endswith("# SETUP")
tests -= nb_setup
```

I'd be happy to read more elegant answers.